# Meaning of "His legs were put together" in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> The new Pope of Fools was brought out in
>   triumph. It was then that everyone realized
>   the man had not been making a face—this
>   was his real face! Indeed, his whole body was
>   ugly. His head was covered with coarse red
>   hair. Between his shoulders rose an enormous
>   hump. **His legs were strangely put together**,
>   and his hands and feet were huge. Still, there
>   was an air of strength and courage about him.
>   He looked like a giant who had been broken
>   into pieces and then carelessly reassembled.

Dose it mean: His leg was like parenthesis and when he walked his leg met each other?

Answer (score 3):

"To put [something] together" is to assemble it. So "strangely put together" means they (his legs) were "assembled" in a strange way.

If this is a real human being, the author is speaking figuratively, and he means that the legs of the Pope of Fools are malformed. He must have some kind of deformity. (It looks *as if* his legs had been assembled incorrectly in some factory or workshop.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it could either mean his legs literally came together like you describe, maybe at the knees - or just that his legs looked strange in a general way, where "put together" would mean "built" or even "neat/attractive" (though in a strange way - but this is less likely given the other negative descriptions of his appearance). See the different definitions of "put together" here: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+together